# for loop for querySelectorALL

Tags: javascript

I am trying to put the value of the input textfield into my 'data' array, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. When I do `console.log(input)` inside the for loop, the values I enter inside the textfield appear. But when I do `console.log(data)`, it just appears as `{text : ""}`.

```
            var inputText = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='text']");
            var input = "";

            for(var index = 0; index < inputText.length; index++){
                input = inputText[index].value;
                //console.log(input);
            }

            var data = {'text' : input};

            //console.log(data);
```

Comment: You need to .push the object and do that inside the loop:`var data = []; for(var index = 0; index < inputText.length; index++){
                input = inputText[index].value; data.push({'text' : input});
                
            }`

Comment: Learn about [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods_2) methods: you can do that with `Array.from(inputText).map(elem => elem.value)`.

Comment: it's not quite clear if you need the values from multiple elements or a single one because you mention single "value of the input textfield", but also mention "array" and "values". Also, `{'text' : input}` is not array but object (`[]` is used for Array object)

Answer (score 1):

you can do so using  [`array push function`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp) try this :

```js
            var inputText = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='text']");
            var data = [];
     
            for(var index = 0; index < inputText.length; index++){
                data.push(inputText[index].value);
            }

            
            console.log(data);
```

```html
<input type="text" name="test" value="test" />
```

Comment: Already answered in the comment. Not worth answering in my opinion but you are not actually pushing anything to data

Comment: @mplungjan how is that , the comment section is for comment and there is the answer section.

Comment: we are here to help each other not to making some you should not answer this comment ;)

Comment: I fixed your code for you. We are also here to help future users

Answer (score -1):

`querySelectorAll` is for multiple elements, and `querySelector` for a single element. To get specific element, the common practice is to assign unique `id` (no other elements should use the same `id`):

```js
var input1 = document.getElementById("input1")

var data = { text: input1.value }

console.log(data)
```

```html
<input id="input1" value="1">
<input id="input2" value="2">
```